# Does ServiceStack web service support sessions?

Tags: .net, servicestack, middleware

Just wondering if ServiceStack web services can preserve state.

Comment: Have you tried googling? This was the first hit in google: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions.

Comment: I searched "servicestack web service preserve state" and it turned up nothing. should have also searched for "session" ;P

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  Quoting from the page that Steven linked:

> The AuthFeature (plugin) already enables the SessionFeature, but if you want to make use of sessions and don't want to enable the built-in Authentication, you will need to register it manually in your AppHost with:
>
> ```
>     public override void Configure(Container container)
>     {
>         Plugins.Add(new SessionFeature());
>     }
> ```
>
> When the SesionFeature is enabled, a Global RequestFilter is added to ServiceStack to ensure that all requests have a Temporary ss-id and a Permanent ss-pid session cookies set. These Cookies just contain a unique Base64-encoded Guid. The ss-opt cookie just stores the users preference on whether they want their current session to be temporary or permanent (i.e. to Remember Me or not - Default is Temporary). Permanent session cookie ss-pid will be created even if ss-opt is Temporary - that helps you to link subsequent requests together and can be used for user request analyzing.